# Can't get a basic for loop working in Typescript

Tags: angular, typescript, for-loop

I'm new to Typescript and Angular other than Angular 1. I'm just trying to do the basicest most basic for loop and it just won't work.

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {

    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

I keep getting those errors.

```
ERROR in src/app/app.component.ts(10,7): error TS1138: Parameter declaration expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(10,28): error TS1005: ';' expected.
src/app/app.component.ts(13,1): error TS1128: Declaration or statement expected.
```

I tried a lot of synthaxes I found out on the internet but nothing works. 
Angular : 8.0.2
Angular CLI : 8.0.3
Node : 10.14.0

Comment: This is happening on line 17. What does the code look like before that line?

Comment: The usual Angular stuff and I declare an array (I tried without declaring the array).

Comment: The error is probably in that code. What's posted here doesn't have any issues.

Comment: Share the entire `app.component.ts` file. Make sure that you've included these lines inside a method/constructor.

Comment: Use ‘let’ instead of ‘var’. (Does not solve the issue, but since you are using Typescript it is better to use let)

Comment: I removed everything I added and updated the code. Using let causes even more errors.

Comment: Did you install typescript using npm? did you use angular cli to create the app? ‘ng new myApp’

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For statements cannot be children of class declarations. This is not valid syntax:

```
export class AppComponent {
    for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        console.log(i);
    }
}
```

Move that into a method or constructor or somewhere else that allows a for statement to appear. For example:

```
export class AppComponent {
    constructor() {
        for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            console.log(i);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It was possible with Angular 1 I didn't konw it changed thank you.

Comment: @AntoineOlivier it wasn't possible with Angular 1. They're both using the same language and the language has never allowed this.